# Building a custom database in C with/without SQL?

Tags: database-recommendation, full-text-search, nosql, embedded

Provide link or tutorials to build a custom database management in C. I am looking for Full Text Search options of about 10GB DB.

Comment: `Provide link or  tutorials` is really not a way to start a good question on the SE network.  Please give us the **SPECIFIC** issue you are trying to resolve.

Comment: @JNK I want to resolve the issue of Full Text Search with Encrypted Database that Deeply Embedded in my Application

Comment: @JNK Kindly open the question again as many are showing interest in this question

Comment: I just voted on it, I didn't close it on my own.  There were 4 other users that helped.  If you IMPROVE  the question, we can vote to reopen it as well.  Just because people are interested doesn't make it a good question.

Answer (score 2):

You many want to look into using the [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) Search tools.

It allows you to create a MySQL instance that runs on port 9036 and only stores indexing info along with keys into real MySQL databases/tables.

There is a [third party MySQL Storage Engine called SphinxSE](http://www.howtoforge.com/sphinx-as-mysql-storage-engine-sphinxse).

Theoretically, the keys can you store in Sphinx do not have to be for MySQL. They could be for any DBMS. Sphinx is just a good key store that is built for FULLTEXT indexing.

Now, if you need to access the Sphinx DB using C/C++, then you need [CodeBase](http://www.codebase.com/products/).